# drracket doesn't work on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

When I try to use `drracket` on Ubuntu 12.04, I get this error:

```
ffi-lib: couldn't open "libjpeg.so.62" (libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

 === context ===
/usr/lib/racket/collects/racket/draw/unsafe/jpeg.rkt: [running body]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/racket/draw/private/bitmap.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/racket/draw/private/dc.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/racket/draw/private/svg-dc.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/racket/draw.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/mred/private/kernel.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/mred/private/const.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/mred/private/check.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/mred/private/mred.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/mred/mred.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/mred/main.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/racket/gui/base.rkt: [traversing imports]
/usr/lib/racket/collects/drracket/drracket.rkt: [traversing imports]
```

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 8):

please try

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

and rerun the program.

By the way, I cannot reproduce this error!

Comment: In my case, drracket was closing immediately after opening. Installing libjpeg resolved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

If re-installing does not solve this error, try:

```
locate -i libjpeg
```

This will search all the instances of the library, so you can edit the necesary files with the right path.